# No puedo completar un diccionario a través de dos listas con for

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, diccionarios

Me encuentro aprendiendo python y como dice el titulo estoy intentando completar un diccionario a través de dos listas `for`.

```
verduleria{}

lista_de_frutas=["banana","manzana","ciruela","sandía"]
lista_de_colores=["amarilla","verde","morado","rojo"]



for frutas in lista_de_frutas:

     for colores in lista_de_colores:
   
         verduleria[frutas]=[colores]

print(verduleria)
```

Completa las keys del diccionario de buena forma pero no los values, ya que los completa a todo el diccionario con el value=rojo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema se puede resolver de varias formas, te dejo dos:

### Con loop

Si quieres hacer un bucle `for` por que lo estás practicando, tu problema es el que ha indicado @gbianchi, **siempre te va a quedar el último color como valor de tus diccionarios** porque es el último `for` que se ejecuta en todas las verduras.

SI quiere evitar esto, utiliza solo un `for` y busca por indice dentro de las listas:

```
verduleria = {}
for idx in range(len(lista_de_frutas)):
    verduleria[lista_de_frutas[idx]] = lista_de_colores[idx]
```

**Salida:**

```
{'banana': 'amarilla',
 'manzana': 'verde',
 'ciruela': 'morado',
 'sandía': 'rojo'}
```

En este caso utilizamos `len()` que nos da la longitud de un objeto [documentación oficial de len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) y `range()` que nos da un iterador hasta el número indicado [documentación oficial de range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Con esto lo que se hace es coger un indice y recorrer ambas listas por el indice.

También se puede usar `enumerate()` [documentación oficial de enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for idx, fruta in enumerate(lista_de_frutas):
    verduleria[fruta] = lista_de_colores[idx]
```

En este caso como vemos en la documentación oficial `enumerate()` también devuelve un iterador, cada elemento es una tupla, que contiene dos elementos, el indice que ocupa una fruta, y la fruta que es. Por lo que utilizamos la fruta como clave, y con el indice buscamos en la lista de colores, su color.

### Con zip

Una forma más avanzada es usar `zip()` [documentación oficial zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Esta función lo que hace es unir iterables por su indice. Es decir, en nuestro caso tenemos dos listas y unimos cada par de elementos por su indice (el primero de la primera lista con el primero de la segunda lista, el segundo de la primera lista, con el segundo de la segunda lista, etc...)

```
dict(zip(lista_de_frutas, lista_de_colores))
```

En este caso `zip()` devuelve un iterador por lo que lo podemos convertir a diccionario, con la función `dict` directamente, el resultado sería igual que con las otras opciones anteriores:

**Salida**

```
{'banana': 'amarilla',
 'manzana': 'verde',
 'ciruela': 'morado',
 'sandía': 'rojo'}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda,es de gran utilidad.

Answer (score 2):

No soy experto en python, pero tu problema es totalmente de logica...

```
for frutas in lista_de_frutas:
    for colores in lista_de_colores:
        verduleria[frutas]=[colores]
```

El loop de frutas, recorre todas las frutas...
El segundo loop recorre todos los colores...

por lo cual, tu codigo esta agarrando banana, y para verduleria[banana], le estas agregando en la segunda iteracion todos los colores.. hasta el rojo.. entonces, siempre queda el rojo... para todas las verduras...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!